# Why isn't a child class limited by the parent's properties?

Tags: c#, oop

Assuming I have two classes as follows:

```
class Fruit
{
    public string color { get; set; }
}
class Orange : Fruit
{
    public double diameter { get; set; }
}
```

And then create an orange object inside a fruit variable

```
Fruit fruit = new Orange() { color = "Orange", diameter = 10.0 };

// This line prints 10 even though the Fruit class doesn't contain a
// diameter property
Console.WriteLine( ( (Orange) fruit ).diameter );
```

How come the whole orange, including the diameter property, can squeeze into the fruit variable? Why isn't the fruit variable limited by the Fruit class definition?

What would be the difference if I put the new Orange inside an Orange variable instead, as in this example?

```
Orange fruit = new Orange() { color = "Orange", diameter = 10.0 };
```

The only difference I can find is if I make type tests on the variables, and that I don't need a cast before using the object. But there must be more to it than that, right?

Comment: That's exactly what casting is all about... It would be useless otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Fruit` is a generalization , while `Orange` is a specialization . Specialized objects can improvise on the existing inherited attributes or can have added properties specific to it.

*How come the whole orange, including the diameter property, can squeeze into the fruit variable?*

`fruit` is only a reference variable but it refers to the new `Orange` object which resides probably in the heap . The `Orange` object is defined big enough to hold the `diameter` property . Superclass reference type can refer to subclass objects . This way you can implement Polymorphism . If you do something like this `fruit.color` , then at run time you can access the `color` property of any subclass which extends `Fruit` and whose object the `fruit` is currently referring to.

*Why isn't the fruit variable limited by the Fruit class definition?*

When you do this :

```
Fruit fruit = new Orange() { color = "Orange", diameter = 10.0 };
```

You are giving yourself a chance to implement **Polymorphism** in your code. If you declare a method passing `Fruit` type as an argument , then you can use the `Fruit` type reference variable to access properties or invoke methods on it without actually restricting your method to a specific `Fruit` type . In future , if you want to change the specific fruit from `Orange` to `Apple` , where `Apple` extends `Fruit` , then you can re-use that method and be sure at least the methods or properties defined in `Fruit` will work for that specific fruit type.

*What would be the difference if I put the new Orange inside an Orange variable instead*

As I mentioned earlier , if you use specific type reference , then you cannot take advantage of Polymorphism.

Comment: So fruit becomes as an interface rather than a limiting variable, if I understood you correctly?

Comment: @Ohlin It can be a class with some implementation defined which is common to other base class , while base class can override those methods or add specific methods too.

Answer (score 1):

This is called runtime-polymorphism. The `Orange` extends the fruit and adds new properties, such as *diameter*.
When you create an object of `Orange` and put it into a `Fruit`, it retains its properties, only that fruit cannot address these. You would then need to make an `Orange` of the `Fruit` again, to get the diameter.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)

> In computer science, polymorphism is a programming language feature that allows values of different data types to be handled using a uniform interface. The concept of parametric polymorphism applies to both data types and functions. A function that can evaluate to or be applied to values of different types is known as a polymorphic function. A data type that can appear to be of a generalized type (e.g., a list with elements of arbitrary type) is designated polymorphic data type like the generalized type from which such specializations are made.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically because you are creating Orange and the Fruit is the generalization of an Orange. It is just a wrapper of an actual Orange object. The important thing is you are creating Orange and assigning it as a Fruit, but the Fruit is an orange. If you do

```
Fruit _fruit = new Fruit()
```

that would be different. Your are creating Orange and that Orange inherits from Fruit and that is why you can write like that.